# Stop jQuery validations on Cancel button

Tags: jquery, validation, for-loop

I am using predefined cssclass to validate the form using jQuery.

When I click on cancel button all validation in the form firing. How can I stop those validation for cancel button?

Comment: How about you share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to remove the class "submit" for cancel button and "submit" class only for submit button